Why does my VS code terminal have a weird title
Hi I am new to coding and python in general. I am working on getting familiar with VS Code and the terminal has a weird title compared to the videos I am watching to learn. While the video's terminal just has $ mine has nehamaan@Nehas-MacBook-Air squiggly line % /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 and on. So how do I fix this? What does it mean?
I tried uninstalling but didnt work.

Because macos uses zsh instead of bash and they have different prompts defined by default.

That is your system's prompt. There are similarities, but you can expect everything and whatnot depending on what system you are working with.
You can customize it by changing the $PS1 environment variable, but save that for later. Enjoy your programming journey!
